# textFieldShouldReturn in custom UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem with my textField, I have done everything possible but I'm not sure what the problem is, I need to get the updated value of textField. Attached below is the implementation of my custom tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class SnippetCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var snippetId: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var snippetParameter: UITextField!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        snippetParameter.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        snippetParameter.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        snippetParameter.clipsToBounds = true
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did end editing method called")
        snippetParameter.text = textField.text!

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("TEXT->",textField.text ?? "")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
    }
}
```

Comment: in the awakeFromnib ,  check if the outlet is available or not,

Comment: Connect the delegate in Interface Builder

Comment: Do you mean connect it to the cell, i did still not working..

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong if it is implemented `awakeFromNib` , it will not be a part of ViewController and only be a part of custom cell, the textfield is in table. It should be in `cellForRow` ...

```
cell.snippetParameter.delegate = self
```

Comment: check outlet is connected ?

Comment: try to move delegate method in controller

Comment: what outlet ? do u mean delegate connected to the controller? i did that